# Modify List View Query of Helpdesk module

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am using vTiger 6.4 and trying to modify list view query of help desk module.

I have tried by modifying the function `getListQuery()` from `\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php` but no effect if i changed anything from it. If anyone knows the file path to modify the where condition then please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modules\Vtiger\models\ListView.php
change below function $listQuery query 
getListViewEntries